# Could A Dynamic System Approximate To Spherical Harmonics?

Tags: physics, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, spherical-harmonics

Spherical harmonics describes electron orbitals in the Schrodinger equation. However the possibility remains that electron orbitals are dynamic systems of interacting particles that merely approximate to the statistical Schrodinger equation. Therefore, **what mathematical properties would two particles need to interact in a manner that dynamically establishes spherical harmonics?** For the sake of simplicity it may be convenient to consider only two particles as in Hydrogen.

Comment: I do need to understand the way you want to approach exactly before being able to answer on the focus. So my first question is: what would be the difference between an atomic orbital function and what you are looking for?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi Beyond being a dynamic interaction of two particles, the desired particles must occupy an exact position and momentum at all times, which is not allowed in modern atomic orbital theory. For example: $Y^0_0(\theta,\phi)$, which is spherical, would require that the two interacting particles have velocity perpendicular to their radial acceleration: since those are universal properties of spherical orbits. It gets more tricky with higher orders of $Y^n_n(\theta,\phi)$.

Comment: Thanks. Built on the previous question this would mean that in contrast to the stochastic model (classic) you will need to build the **stochastic moments** up to higher order of state variables what would allow (hypothetically) to translate a stochastic model to mesoscopic or macroscopic level of state variables (such as we do for instance in laser theory to macroscopic modes), isnt it? Higher orders of state variables $Y$ then hypothetically correspond to those stocahstic moments. Does my thoughts make sense?

Comment: See please in this direction as well>>> http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01326496

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9914/discussion-between-joehobbit-and-al-hwarizmi)

Comment: Fine with me lets go there